# how to accessing sqlite database from java class

Tags: android

I have created sqlite database using phonegap.
I am able to access that databse within the javascript.
But I want access that sqlitedatabase from java class. It is possible?

Comment: Is phone gap that web development thing? If so you'll need to load your sqlite stuff through code that is then compiled. There's loads of stuff about this online: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Are you really accessing your database through javascript though? This seems rather insecure but I'm not experienced enough with phone gap to say it for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PhoneGap --SQLite  you can use Pluggin available on GIT HUB.
there is javafile also.please check out the link:[Sqlite Database](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PhoneGap compatibility, but, as far as Android, WebView control and JavaScript is concern, you do have a solution.

You should consider using WebView's addJavascriptInterface.. This will expose any of your Java objects as a JavaScript object. So, you could create a class that encapsulate the SQLite functionality you want expose and sent it through.

Answer (score 1):

As said above in the answer by BicycleDude. U need to create a class and expose it and use it inside javascript.

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/eb9c4a350482f86f

This link contains the reference to make toast inside javascript.U can use this similarly to access database.One problem is how u handle the returned cursor.may be u can use JSON

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I am getting null pointer exception at appview in the following code                                 WebView appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);       MyToaster toaster = new MyToaster(this, appView);           appView.addJavascriptInterface(toaster,"MyToaster");

Comment: just follow that it works perfectly fine for me. WebView appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); is not required i think